# Why use MKL's Zgemm when gemm3m is the same but faster?

Tags: linear-algebra, blas, intel-mkl

According to MKL's [documentation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-gemm3m):

> The ?gemm3m routines perform a matrix-matrix operation with general
>   complex matrices. These routines are similar to the ?gemm routines,
>   but they use fewer matrix multiplication operations.

and

> These routines perform a complex matrix multiplication by forming the
>   real and imaginary parts of the input matrices. This uses three real
>   matrix multiplications and five real matrix additions instead of the
>   conventional four real matrix multiplications and two real matrix
>   additions. The use of three real matrix multiplications reduces the
>   time spent in matrix operations by 25%, resulting in significant
>   savings in compute time for large matrices.

If this is the case, why is Zgemm not deprecated? What's the catch here? Is using Zgemm ever better? A batched version of gemm3m also exists, which means that it is useful for small matrices as well.

Answer (score 3):

Just found this question recently when looking for the same answer as you. While I can't 100% confirm Intels reasoning and decision for using the normal 4 matrix multiplication over the 3M version in the standard zgemm implementation, this paper: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/3086466 (available in pdf here: http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/flame/pubs/blis6_toms_rev0.pdf) seems to suggest that the 3M method has higher numerical rounding errors than the 4M version, which may be why people (especially those using single precision) are cautious for using it by default.

Answer (score 1):

Because the second one its to perform an operation with complex values. When you do an operation with real values, just one multiplication its needed. When you do an operation with complex values, you need 4 matrix multiplication. This method offer an improve on the method reducing the number of matrix multiplication from 4 to 3. When your input its a real value, the everyday gemm functions its the best choice.